# mysql select into returns NULL

Tags: mysql

Please help me understand,
I need to make stored procedure for creating new user into db.

```
    delimiter //    
    CREATE PROCEDURE add_user (x VARCHAR(25))
    BEGIN
      DECLARE x VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'mark';
      DECLARE newname VARCHAR(25);
      DECLARE xid INT;

      SELECT x, id INTO newname, xid
        FROM users WHERE x = x;
      SELECT newname;
    END;
    delimiter ;
```

when i `call add_user('peter');`
it shows me:
         `newname/null`
where do i go wrong ?

Comment: `WHERE xname = xname`?

Comment: my bad,sorry,changed that `xname to x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_user (x VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
  DECLARE x VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'mark';
```

This actually creates *two* variables named `x`. The first is the function parameter, and the second is a local variable which is in scope inside the `BEGIN ... END` block. According to MySQL's [scoping rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html), only one of these variables can be visible, which means that the parameter `x` is hidden and inaccessible inside the `BEGIN ... END` block.

The solution is simply to delete the line

```
  DECLARE x VARCHAR(25) DEFAULT 'mark';
```

and, if you need to assign a default value, do it in an `IF` block:

```
IF x IS NULL THEN
  SET x = 'mark';
END IF;
```

The complete function definition should be

```
delimiter //    
CREATE PROCEDURE add_user (x VARCHAR(25))
BEGIN
  DECLARE newname VARCHAR(25);
  DECLARE xid INT;

  IF x IS NULL THEN
    SET x = 'mark';
  END IF;

  SELECT x, id INTO newname, xid
    FROM users WHERE x = x;
  SELECT newname;
END;
delimiter ;
```